# Loop Canvas element in Angular2

Tags: angular, canvas, charts

Below is the component.html page

```js
<tr *ngFor="let item of items;let i=index">
       <td><b>{{item.name}}</b><br/>{{item.desc}}</td>
       <td>
          <canvas id="canvas" baseChart #kpichart></canvas>
       </td>
    </tr>
```

Below is the component.ts file

```js
   @ViewChild('kpichart') kpichart: ElementRef; 
   let lineCtx = this.kpichart.nativeElement.getContext('2d');
   var myChart = new Chart(lineCtx, {
      type: 'line',
     data: {
         labels: this.lineChartLabels,
         datasets:this.lineChartData
       }
   });
```

Not able to display multiple chart in page.
How to loop canvas element chart using *ngFor
Please help

Thanks in Advance

Comment: what data do you have in 'items' ?

Comment: Based on the item.id  I will fetch the data for the graph.Items will contain the name and description. I am able to display only one graph based on the above code. For each item i need to display graph.

Comment: <canvas-chart [canvas]=item.item_id></canvas-chart>

Answer (score 0):

Created a separate component and pass the id to the component and chart is plotted.

component.html

`<canvas-chart [canvas]=item.item_id></canvas-chart>`

and in

child-component.ts

```
 @Input() canvas;
 @ViewChild('kpichart') kpichart: ElementRef;
```

child-component.html

```
<div style="display:block"><canvas baseChart #kpichart></canvas></div>
```